# Wireless debugging for the Apple Watch in Xcode 9 and iOS 11?

Tags: xcode, apple-watch

I successfully setup wireless debugging on my iPhone and iPad via Xcode 9 and iOS 11, and wondered if this is also possible for the Apple Watch?

Answer (score 0):

Beta 4 is out today with Apple Watch Wireless Development support.